# Detect user device and assign different jquery (desktop / mobile(ipad)) in js/ jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, device

```
<script src="jsv3/jquery.js"></script>
<!--<script src="jsv3/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>-->
```

Currently I have insert script for desktop version only because I found that declare two jquery will occur error. Are there any way to check the device type and select different jquery plugin for corresponding device? Thanks

Comment: Can you use a server side language, such as PHP? If you can, this might help: http://detector.dmolsen.com/

Comment: unfortunely I can only use js/jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to detect the client. Following example involves `userAgent` to detect the type of client device.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
             || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
             || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
             || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
             || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
             || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
             || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {


          var file=document.createElement("link");
          file.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
          file.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
          file.setAttribute("href", "css/alternate_css_file.css");
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file);

          var file_2= document.createElement("script");
          file_2.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
          file_2.setAttribute("src", "js/alternate_js_file.js");
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file_2);

    }

    });
```

This is a general solution for detecting client devices. You may have to use different CSS for tablets clients like iPad.

Comment: if the jquery follow by some other jquery script e.g. jquery ui , it return me error of jquery is undefined. However, I see the <script type="text/javascript" src="jsv3/jquery.js"></script> , how to fix this? thx

Answer (score 1):

```
if (navigator.userAgent=="<type>"){ //check your device type

  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
```

HTH